# C++ Counting specific records in a files through 2D arrays

Tags: c++, arrays

Let's say I have a file that contains data of male and female. How would I go about counting those records? I just need a starting point to build on. I don't need anyone to do my homework for me.

Data below..

Thanks

```
Number,Gender,GivenName,Surname,Birthday,BloodType,Pounds,FeetInches
1,male,Joseph,Doody,1/10/1968,A-,179.5,5' 7"
2,male,Robert,King,8/17/1985,A+,203.1,5' 10"
3,male,Richard,Murphy,3/18/1944,O+,235.6,6' 1"
4,female,Caroline,Acosta,5/27/1959,B+,145.4,5' 8"
5,male,John,Capps,12/18/1967,O+,186.6,5' 9"
6,female,Stephanie,Guidry,3/25/1981,O+,177.8,5' 6"
7,female,Janet,Kimmel,2/23/1977,A+,161.3,5' 7"
8,male,Jerrell,Wright,8/4/1929,B+,140.6,5' 9"
9,female,Cheryl,Johnson,12/8/1972,A+,128.7,5' 1"
10,female,Sandra,Gonzalez,6/1/1974,A+,171.4,5' 9"
11,male,Kevin,Noel,9/30/1939,O+,212.1,5' 6"
12,female,Krysta,Booth,7/9/1940,O+,173.1,5' 3"
13,male,Sam,Clark,7/5/1979,A+,162.4,5' 9"
14,male,James,Graves,8/15/1959,A+,235.0,5' 8"
15,male,Elton,Fink,6/30/1937,A+,198.4,5' 5"
16,male,Robert,Daniels,10/14/1969,O+,173.4,5' 7"
17,male,Joel,Carnahan,12/25/1993,O-,124.7,6' 0"
18,female,Elizabeth,Rogers,6/4/1988,O+,132.4,5' 6"
19,male,Charles,Johnston,2/3/1969,A+,161.3,5' 10"
20,female,Francisca,Thornberry,1/7/1954,O+,221.1,5' 1"
21,male,Derick,Smith,12/24/1951,A+,149.6,6' 0"
22,female,Tara,Mayhew,7/2/1958,A+,128.7,5' 2"
23,male,Phillip,Williamson,4/13/1991,B+,143.2,6' 0"
24,male,Jerry,Kay,7/24/1944,B+,163.7,5' 8"
25,female,Bessie,Hosford,12/17/1957,AB+,210.3,5' 7"
26,female,Sally,Love,11/25/1969,AB+,166.3,5' 2"
27,female,Jessica,Smith,12/5/1947,A+,201.7,5' 8"
28,female,Gay,Falcon,3/19/1949,O+,213.8,5' 3"
29,female,Aurora,Schultz,6/4/1937,O-,180.6,5' 1"
30,male,Steve,Bushnell,1/18/1974,B+,236.3,5' 7"
31,male,James,Brown,10/15/1967,A+,151.6,5' 9"
32,female,Lorena,Grey,3/25/1975,B+,200.9,5' 1"
33,male,Edward,Washington,9/8/1981,O-,174.9,6' 1"
34,female,Ellen,Pope,5/6/1927,A+,119.7,5' 2"
35,female,Linda,Tyler,10/9/1952,O-,149.2,5' 5"
36,male,Tyler,Stewart,5/20/1974,B+,199.5,5' 10"
37,male,Peter,Hayner,11/11/1962,B+,228.6,5' 6"
38,male,Matthew,Horn,12/28/1972,O+,220.2,5' 10"
39,female,Felecia,Brown,4/6/1972,A-,123.0,5' 9"
40,male,Kenneth,Thompson,10/13/1935,O+,137.9,5' 5"
41,male,Arthur,Gonzalez,12/14/1964,A+,160.6,5' 7"
42,male,Wilbur,Small,9/24/1982,B+,174.5,6' 0"
43,male,Anthony,Hill,7/11/1972,O+,240.9,6' 2"
44,male,Elbert,Coward,10/9/1984,O+,134.0,5' 11"
45,male,Stephan,Leonhardt,8/6/1928,O+,215.4,5' 5"
46,male,Richard,Lawson,1/18/1975,O-,240.7,5' 9"
47,female,Elizabeth,Coaxum,5/27/1952,A+,201.1,5' 0"
48,male,Francisco,Williamson,6/12/1959,A+,180.2,6' 1"
49,female,Charlotte,Taylor,3/5/1972,O+,127.8,5' 1"
50,male,Edward,Wickham,12/11/1983,A+,153.3,5' 9"
51,male,John,Gonzalez,9/28/1964,A+,247.1,5' 10"
52,male,Emil,Turner,9/3/1934,A+,191.4,6' 0"
53,female,Kathleen,Meyers,4/10/1939,A+,215.2,5' 7"
54,female,Leslie,Hunt,10/7/1943,AB+,143.2,5' 0"
55,male,Samuel,Claunch,7/27/1939,B+,195.8,5' 9"
56,female,Precious,Bland,10/4/1992,AB+,148.1,5' 3"
57,female,Alice,Miles,10/17/1932,A+,214.1,5' 4"
58,female,Marsha,Baker,3/16/1971,O+,175.3,5' 7"
59,female,Catherine,Williams,4/19/1986,O+,125.8,5' 1"
60,male,Joshua,Jones,7/12/1956,O+,220.2,5' 11"
61,female,Nancy,Wood,9/12/1946,B+,210.8,5' 3"
62,male,John,Lovely,1/28/1952,A+,178.6,6' 2"
63,male,Earnest,Valle,7/19/1941,O+,140.6,5' 9"
64,female,Tara,Thomas,12/20/1953,A+,197.1,5' 4"
65,male,Grady,Farrington,2/11/1985,O-,182.2,6' 2"
66,female,Brenda,Wallace,3/29/1955,A+,216.5,5' 5"
67,male,Travis,Guyton,5/17/1928,O-,132.2,5' 4"
68,male,Glen,McLaren,11/6/1984,B+,171.8,5' 10"
69,female,Lori,Hughes,8/5/1939,B+,171.2,5' 7"
70,female,Ida,Harris,7/31/1950,B+,167.0,5' 6"
71,male,Thomas,Scoville,4/23/1951,A-,183.7,6' 0"
72,male,John,Tan,3/7/1936,A-,179.3,5' 6"
73,female,Valerie,McMillian,8/15/1970,O+,216.0,5' 1"
74,male,Jay,Thomas,1/14/1970,O+,154.9,5' 11"
75,male,Kenneth,Snowden,3/16/1939,B+,140.8,5' 6"
76,male,Robert,Duran,8/13/1981,O+,141.0,5' 11"
77,male,Alton,McKinney,6/18/1988,A+,216.3,5' 6"
78,male,William,Read,4/6/1972,O+,205.3,5' 9"
79,male,James,Mitchell,4/21/1990,A+,132.2,5' 10"
80,female,Clara,Lambeth,2/28/1953,O+,154.7,5' 7"
81,female,Lee,Price,11/24/1961,B+,173.6,5' 7"
82,female,Anna,Martin,9/4/1985,AB+,156.0,5' 8"
83,male,Jerome,Abramson,3/30/1959,B+,164.3,5' 7"
84,female,Paula,Terry,11/21/1956,B+,132.4,5' 1"
85,female,Mary,Weyand,2/5/1949,AB+,224.6,5' 3"
86,female,Barbara,Toner,1/5/1986,O+,192.1,5' 3"
87,male,Brett,Eliason,8/5/1931,B+,141.2,5' 7"
88,female,Mercedes,Murphy,11/28/1938,AB+,184.4,5' 5"
89,female,Judith,Bischoff,11/24/1982,A+,216.5,5' 8"
90,female,Karen,Simmons,9/13/1974,O+,114.0,5' 5"
91,male,Sonny,Donnelly,6/27/1943,B+,173.8,5' 5"
92,female,Leah,Delong,12/29/1935,A+,128.7,4' 11"
93,male,Steven,Hildebrand,5/18/1970,A+,206.8,5' 8"
94,female,Terry,Cuellar,2/19/1948,A-,203.1,5' 3"
95,female,Daisy,Pease,7/31/1932,A+,153.6,4' 11"
96,female,Lorrie,Bullock,10/27/1976,B+,152.9,5' 9"
97,female,Evelyn,Teel,12/13/1992,O+,111.3,5' 5"
98,male,Brett,Dawson,3/3/1966,A+,148.7,6' 1"
99,female,Sandra,Scheer,5/15/1992,AB+,190.1,5' 7"
100,male,James,Helsel,8/29/1957,A+,235.2,6' 2"
```

Comment: what do you mean by counting? Counting what?

Comment: 1. Read csv into array: https://www.google.com.au/#hl=en&sclient=psy-ab&q=c%2B%2B+read+csv+into+array&oq=c%2B%2B+read+csv+into+array&gs_l=serp.3..0i13j0i8i13i30l2.2331.2723.1.2882.2.2.0.0.0.0.186.186.0j1.1.0...0.0...1c.1.12.psy-ab.CuPlfCRGUfU&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=fab74f83f700d76d&biw=952&bih=999 2. Loop over your array to count whatever.

Comment: If the containers you are using support iterators use `std::count` or `std::count_if` as appropriate. Pointers are bidirectional iterators so even if you are using arrays those functions can still be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd probably start by defining a `struct` to represent one record of data.

Then I'd define `operator>>` for that struct type. I'd probably start with `std::getline` to read up to the next comma to read a single field in each record.

I'd use that to read the data into a vector, to make it easy to sort, count, partition, etc.

Comment: See now that makes sense. Dealing with Professors who explain little over an online course, leaves noobs like me to resort to site like this for more insight.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Look [Here](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/13087/) for a guide on c++ reading for csv files.

You can simply read file into a set of vector. You can then sort them into male, female, etc. Anything you want!

Comment: @MudbubbleBenton It looks comma separated to me. csv just means comma separated values, it does not need to have a specific file name.